# Python - rearrange and write strings (line splitting, unwanted newline)

Tags: python

I have a script that:

- Reads in each line of a file
- Finds the '*' character in each line and splits the line here
- Rearranges the 3 parts (first to last, and last to first)
- Writes the rearranged strings to a .txt file

Problem is, it's finding some new line character or something, and isn't outputting how it should. Have tried stripping newline chars, but there must be something I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any help!

the script:

```
## Import packages
import time
import csv

## Make output file
file_output = open('output.txt', 'w')

## Open file and iterate over, rearranging the order of each string
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f:

    ## Jump to next line (skips file headers)
    next(f)

    ## Split each line, rearrange, and write the new line
    for line in f:

        ## Strip newline chars
        line = line.strip('\n')

        ## Split original string
        category, star, value = line.rpartition("*")

        ##Make new string
        new_string = value+star+category+'\n'

        ## Write new string to file
        file_output.write(new_string)

file_output.close()

## Require input (stops program from immediately quitting)
k = input("  press any key to exit")
```

Input file (input.csv):

```
Category*Hash Value
1*FB1124FF6D2D4CD8FECE39B2459ED9D5
1*FB1124FF6D2D4CD8FECE39B2459ED9D5
1*FB1124FF6D2D4CD8FECE39B2459ED9D5
1*34AC061CCCAD7B9D70E8EF286CA2F1EA
```

Output file (output.txt)

```
FB1124FF6D2D4CD8FECE39B2459ED9D5
*1
FB1124FF6D2D4CD8FECE39B2459ED9D5
*1
FB1124FF6D2D4CD8FECE39B2459ED9D5
*1
34AC061CCCAD7B9D70E8EF286CA2F1EA
*1
```

EDIT: Answered. Thanks everyone! Looks all good now! :)

Comment: Try using `line.strip()` instead of `line.strip('\n')`. I suspect you have one of the other newline characters in there (`\r` or `\r\n`).

Comment: This is written in Python 2 - thanks

Comment: Think that's fixed it! I'm getting the right output now - thanks @ChinmayKanchi

Comment: Why are you opening the text file 'input.csv' as a binary file? You should open it as a text file, and then your platform's local newline sequences will be converted to `\n`. Or you could use universal mode to handle all the usual newline conventions. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open for details.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! Looks like it's fixed now :-)

Answer (score 0):

The file output.txt should exist.

The following work with python2 on debian:

```
## Import packages
import time
import csv

## Make output file
file_output = open('output.txt', 'w')

## Open file and iterate over, rearranging the order of each string
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f:

    ## Jump to next line (skips file headers)
    next(f)

    ## Split each line, rearrange, and write the new line
    for line in f:

        ## Split original string
        category, star, value = line.rpartition("*")

        ##Make new string
        new_string = value.strip()+star+category+'\n'

        ## Write new string to file
        file_output.write(new_string)

file_output.close()

## Require input (stops program from immediately quitting)
k = input("  press any key to exit")
```

I `strip()` the value witch contain the `\n` in order to sanitize it. You used `strip('\n')` which could be ambiguous and just using the method without parameter do the job.

Comment: Could you explain to the readers what you have changed/added? And why you did that?

Comment: Still getting the same output - is there any other information I can provide to help? Thanks

Comment: I have no problem in python2

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DictWriter`

```
import csv

with open('aster.csv') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='*')

    writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, delimiter='*', fieldnames=['Hash Value','Category'])
    #writer.writeheader()
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Without `csv` library

```
with open('aster.csv') as f:
    next(f)

    lines = [line.strip().split('*') for line in f]

    with open('out2.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for line in lines:
            fout.write('%s*%s\n' % (line[1], line[0]))
```